# MB with CPU and power supply - can be turned on but not off

Tags: cpu, power-supply, motherboard

Not sure whether this question belongs here, I hope so. I have just bought a motherboard and CPU.
I have installed the CPU, cooler and connected to CPUFAN on the MB. I have plugged the power supply to MB and the cable from "ON" button to pins named "PWR" and the LEDs.
However when I turn on the PC, both HDD and POWER leds are continously on and the PC cannot be turned out. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check for a short on the bottom of the motherboard.  If you somehow forgot to put in the MB risers, you can cause a bunch of problems like this.

Comment: MB risers? Dont know what are these. I have just installed the MB with the screws.

Comment: They go between the motherboard and the case.  They prevent the contacts on the bottom of the motherboard from shorting out against the computer case.  They are tiny and brass, and have a screw hole on one end, and screw threads on the other. See: http://www.heatonresearch.com/images/article/21/ch3fig4.jpg